# Cannot convert type FLOAT into INT when changing sprites

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am working on a sprite sheet which changes depending on the HP of my character. To create this I have a Heart file which takes the Health object from the player and changes the sprites depending on the Current Health.

While I'm trying to put Current health within the PlayerStats. I have a float for health and max health but apparently, to display the sprite the curHealth has to be an INT.

but whenever I try to interact with the curHealth value, I keep getting the error " Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'.

My Heart file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Hearts : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Sprite[] HeartSprites;
  public Image HeartUI;
  private PlayerStats player;

  void Start (){

    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerStats>();

  }

  void Update (){

    HeartUI.sprite = HeartSprites[player.curHealth];
  }
}
```

The playerStats file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour
{
  public static PlayerStats playerStats;
  public int curHealth;
  public GameObject player;
  public float health;
  public float maxHealth;


  void Awake()
  {
    if(playerStats != null)
    {
      Destroy(playerStats);
    }
    else
    {
      playerStats = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
  }

  void Start()
  {
      health = maxHealth;
      curHealth = maxHealth;
  }

  public void DealDamage(float damage)
  {
    health -= damage;
    CheckDeath();
  }

  public void HealCharacter(float heal)
  {
    health += heal;
    CheckOverheal();
  }

  private void CheckOverheal()
  {
    if(health > maxHealth)
    {
      health = maxHealth;
    }
  }

  private void CheckDeath()
  {
    if(health <= 0)
    {
      Destroy(player);
    }
  }
}
```

While it would have been easier to just connect it with the "float health" component. since it HAS to be an int this doesn't seem to work.
So far I don't have a clue how i'll be able to make the curHealth interactable with these 2 files.

Comment: When I try to play the game and get hit by the enemies. I get " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Which refers to     HeartUI.sprite = HeartSprites[Mathf.RoundToInt(player.curHealth)];

Answer (score 3):

Esiest way would be a cast

```
int intValue = (int) floatValue;
```

however this simply cuts off the decimals.

---

[Ali Baba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241484/7111561) was close but you still have to cast the results to `int` since all the methods he mentioned still return a `float`. E.g.

```
int intValue =  (int)Mathf.Floor(floatValue);
```

---

Better would be to directly use the `int` returning versions like [`Mathf.RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html)

```
int intValue = Mathf.RoundToInt(floatValue);
```

`1.5` -> `2` 
`1.3` -> `1`

or maybe [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) depedning on your needs.

`1.9` -> `1` 
`1.2` -> `1`

---

However you are never actually changing the value of `curHealth` anywhere (except in `Start` .. you should rather implement it maybe as read-only property returning an `int` value based on `health`:

```
public int CurrentHealth
{
    get { return Mathf.RoundToInt(health); }
}
```

so you only have to update `health` using `float` operations and `CurrentHealth` returns the according `int` value automatically.

and then use

```
HeartUI.sprite = HeartSprites[player.CurrentHealth];
```

I wouldn't do this in `Update` though but rather event based in the moment the `health` is actually changed -> either call a method or move the sprite setting into the same component.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but since curHealth is the same as "Health" in my playerStats document. How am I able to document the difference here? Cause if I put anything with curHealth within the start functionality I keep getting errors?

Wouldn't it be easier if I Redirect curHealth to be the same as Health? and then use the Health value which can be decimals?

Comment: I've tried your idea, but it still gives me the same error for some reason. 
Since I still have to interact with the "curHealth" value in the playerStats file/

Answer (score 0):

The error you get refers to this line:

```
curHealth = maxHealth;
```

You declared

```
public int curHealth;
public float maxHealth;
```

As the compiler says, you cannot implicitly convert a `float` to an `int`. You need to cast an explicit conversion.

If you change the offending line to

```
curHealth = (int)maxHealth;
```

The script compiles without errors.

About the other suggestions in the comments, `Mathf.Floor()`returns a float, so you are back to the starting point and need to explicitly cast it `(int)Mathf.Floor()`
Microsoft C# online documentation states that in the explicit casting `(int)myFloat`  "the source value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value, and this integral value becomes the result of the conversion".
So, calling `(int)Mathf.Floor()` is IMHO not necessary, and a waste of resources. 
In case you need to round it in other ways, then e.g. calling `(int)Mathf.Ceil()` would indeed be the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by changing the floats into Int's.
I deleted the whole concept of curHealth and put in

```
HeartUI.sprite = HeartSprites[player.health];
```

In order for the ints to work i put (int) as seen on the examples below

```
  public void DealDamage(float damage)
  {
    health -= (int) damage;
    CheckDeath();
  }

  public void HealCharacter(float heal)
  {
    health += (int) heal;
    CheckOverheal();
  }
```